# AS3 Restore Alpha of Multiple Objects on Click

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I'm creating a simple interactive Mr. Potato Head game using AS3 and have used the following code to make objects disappear on a click. This is an example of the code that handles the Nose.  When the nose is clicked, it disappears. Everything is working as intended; however, I want to include a single button that when clicked will cause all of the pieces (arms, eyes, mouth, etc) to reappear.

```
Nose.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseHandler4);

function mouseHandler4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    Nose.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseHandler4);
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeOut4);
}

function fadeOut4(event:Event):void
{
    var a:Number = Nose.alpha-0.05;
    if (a<=0)
    {
        a = 0;
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeOut4);
    }
    Nose.alpha = a;
}
```

Comment: This is good example for [Object-Oriented Programming (OOP) with Actionscript](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ec0.html). You can create a Body class that has properties like Nose, Eyes, Ears, etc. Within this Body class you could then expose a public method that shows all the pieces. This public method could be used as the function for when the [click event for your button](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/event_handling_as3.html), 'show all pieces' is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make an array of all the clips you want to fade back in;

```
var pieces:Array = [arms, eyes, mouth];
```

then on click, assuming you make a fadeIn function similar to your fadeOut4

```
for (var i:int = 0; i<pieces.length; i++){
  fadeIn(pieces[i]);
}
```